# getTransmissionChannel() is crashing omnet++ simulation

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have this `getTransmissionChannel()` defined in my simple module.
For the following simulation connections it worked perfectly:

```
    CustomedNode1.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> mySwitch.connectedToPort1;
    CustomedNode2.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> mySwitch.connectedToPort2;
    CustomedNode3.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> mySwitch.connectedToPort3;
    CustomedNode4.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> mySwitch.connectedToPort4;
    CustomedNode5.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> mySwitch.connectedToPort5;
```

Then I replaced node5 with another type of node but using the same port and the new connections generated are:

```
    CustomedNode1.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> ibSwitch.connectedToPort1;
    CustomedNode2.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> ibSwitch.connectedToPort2;
    CustomedNode3.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> ibSwitch.connectedToPort3;
    CustomedNode4.Netport <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> ibSwitch.connectedToPort4;
    mySwitch.connectedToPort5 <--> gatewayNode.Netport ;
```

Now the simulation crashes saying `getTransmissionChannel()` no transmission channel found.

> I don't know what happened suddenly. I have just replaced with a new
>   node with same type of net port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`getTransmissionChannel()` returns the transmission. If you don't specify any channels in your links the OMNet++ tranparently replaces with `cIdealChannel` which basically means no channel object has been assigned to the connection.

And in your case after the node replacement  the new connection 
`mySwitch.connectedToPort5 <--> gatewayNode.Netport ;` does not have any channels defined. So IDE replaces with `cIdealChannel` and so `getTransmissionChannel()` cannot find any transmission channel since there is no channel object defined for this connection.

So instead replace

`mySwitch.connectedToPort5 <--> gatewayNode.Netport ;`

To

```
mySwitch.connectedToPort5 <--> LinkDefinedChannel <--> gatewayNode.Netport ;
```

Now `getTransmissionChannel()` should be able to get the transmission channel since you are defining one channel object to this connection.